# Why is this undefined

Tags: javascript, database, angularjs, rest, variables

Why is this invalid / undefined ??

my query:

```
            $scope.timesheets = Sign.query({
            projectId: $scope.selected.project[0],
            startWeek: this.weekStart,
            endWeek: this.weekEnd
        });

        console.log($scope.timesheets);

        console.log($scope.timesheets.sig);

        console.log($scope.timesheets[0].sig);

    };
```

My console logs returns:

```
console.log($scope.timesheets);
```

returns the timesheets array

```
[
    {
        "_id": "54d104718c54c8202654d6cd",
        "__v": 0,
        "sig": "ass...", 
......
```

but when I use console.log(...[0]).sig it returns:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sig' of undefined

and console.log(...sig) returns undefined

Why can't I get timesheets[0].sig  ?

Comment: Most likely the console is playing tricks on you, in that `console.log($scope.timesheets);` doesn't contain that array initially, but does after the asynchronous action completes, and since you didn't open the object in the console until after it completed, it showed the value after it completed rather than before. The array was passed by reference to the console, but the undefined values from the 2nd two console.logs weren't.

Comment: console.log($scope.timesheets[0].sig);

Comment: @KevinB `console.log($scope.timesheets[0].sig);`

Comment: what it is showing when you are only consoling console.log($scope.timesheets[0]);

Comment: what does it says when you output console.log($scope.timesheets.length)

Comment: @KevinB  you are right on the asynchronous part thx ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Sign object is a [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), which means that $scope.timesheets is a resource object containing a promise that will be resolved when it returns from the server. Try this:

```
$scope.timesheets.$promise.then(function (timesheets) {
    console.log(timesheets[0].sig);
});
```

or

```
Sign.query({ /* ... props ... */}, function (timesheets) {
    console.log(timesheets[0].sig);
});
```

The reason you're able to use `console.log($scope.timesheets)` is because it is logging a reference to the object, which is resolved by the time you're looking at it in your console. However, trying to log properties on the object will resolve to `undefined` until the response comes back from the server.